# Create a product and get a blank page. Refresh and it works

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have this problem with prestashop 1.6.1.1

1. I create a product and save it
2. I go to that product page and I get a blank page with just a link "Add to my wishlist). No css, no images, just a blue link.
3. If at this point I press CMD+R, I still get the blank page.
4. But if I press enter normally, I get the page normally loaded with everything; images, css,...

Then if I go to another page and go back to my product page, I get the same problem.

I already tried to clear smarty cache (manually), enable/disable smarty cache, enable/disable CCC, but I still have that problem.

Comment: Have you activated dev mode to see potential errors ? In file `/config/defines.inc.php` set `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);` to `true` and reload your product page to see if there are errors.

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre Yes I did and nothing is shown

Comment: Is there error in your navigator console ? Does the content appear in the source code of your browser ? Did you checked your apache error log file ?

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre No errors in console. Content does not appear, except for the link of course. No error in the logs.